# Finite absolute moment implies finite lesser absolute moments?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, expected-value

I would like to prove that  If $E[|X|^n] < \infty$ for some positive integer $n$, then $E[|X|^m] < \infty$ for all positive integers $m ≤ n$. So far, using Jensen's Inequality, I have that
$$
\infty > E[|X|^n] \geq |E[X]|^n \geq |E[X]|^m.
$$

From here, I'm stuck... Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Write $X = X1_{|X| \leq 1} + X1_{X > 1}.$ Then $|X|^n \leq 1 + |X|^{n+p}$ for all $p > 0.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $n > m$.  Use Holder's inequality with $p = n/m$ and $q = (1-p^{-1})^{-1}$, so that $p^{-1} +q^{-1} = 1$, instead.
$$E[|X|^m] = E[|X|^m \cdot 1] \le E[|X^m|^p]^{1/p} \, E[1^q]^{1/q} = E[|X|^n]^{m/n} < \infty$$
since $E[|X|^n] < \infty$.